# full screen slider with owl carousel

Tags: javascript, css, height, fullscreen, owl-carousel

I have a big request for help with sth. 
I need to set the height to 100% of html & body for owl carousel slider (Full screen). But I need also a little bit place above it.

This is what I did with other slider and what I need to have: http://lukaszradwan.com/

And example with owl carousel http://lukaszradwan.com/pl/

Please resize Your browser vertically to see effect.

Thank You!

EDIT//

It's almost done, but I have another issue. Below the slider there is an empty place, I don't know why lukaszradwan.com/pl

I need to have the same height to cd-main-content class as a viewport. Can You take a look?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // carousel setup
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    slideSpeed : 300,
    pagination : true,
    paginationSpeed : 400,
    singleItem: true,
    autoHeight: true,
    afterMove: top_align,
    navigationText : false,
    afterAction: function(current) {
    current.find('video').get(0).play();
}
  });

  function top_align() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
    console.log('move');
  }

});
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('.owl-pagination').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
      $('.owl-pagination').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Comment: Please read the tag-descriptions;  they will help get the right people looking at your question.  This question has nothing to do with [tag:owl], the Web Ontology Language.  I've retagged your question with [tag:owl-carousel], which is what this appears to be about.

Answer (score 0):

I just added

```
position: absolute;
top: 289px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

to viewport and `margin-bottom: 289px;` to `cd-main-content` and everything works well.